# Applying Time Delay Neural Network to financial events

Tags: time-series, fundamentals, neural-networks, calender, economic-calender

I have an IT background and I would like to use data from a forex calendar like [this one](http://www.dailyfx.com/calendar) to predict prices.

The problem is that calendar news impacts can last for days or weeks or even can effect previous hours to their release.

Since I would like to use this fundamental information as signal for a trading system, I have read about [Time Delay Neural Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_delay_neural_network) and I think it could be useful for this task.

Does anyone knows or can point to references on how can I apply a Time Delay Neural Network to accomplish this? Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to read as reference the following paper:

> Yao, Jingtao, and Chew Lim Tan. "A case study on using neural networks
>   to perform technical forecasting of forex." Neurocomputing 34.1
>   (2000): 79-98.

The authors applied TDNNs to the forex markets and I think it could be useful for you purposes; you can find the pdf version of the paper [here](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jingtao_Yao/publication/222517139_A_case_study_on_using_neural_networks_to_perform_technical_forecasting_of_forex/links/00b49534422f0227e1000000.pdf).

As regards the available tools to construct this kind of model, I know you can implement that in `matlab`, by exploiting `[timedelaynet](http://it.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/timedelaynet.html).

Hope this will help.

Comment: Many thanks! I have been searching for a R TDNN package with no sucess, do you know any?

Comment: I do not know if there exist, but, honestly, I think not; I follow r-bloggers.com and I'm pretty informed about NN field and I know there are mainly two packages about NN: 'nnet' and 'neuralnet'. You should try to adapt those packages to your needing! If you're satisfied about the answer, please mark that, thanks @MithPaul!

Comment: Thanks again @Quantopic, the closest I found is RSNNS package for R: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSNNS/ which has implementations of Elman and Jordan Neural Networks which are both Recurrent Neural Networks. I think that for my purpose they are the same as a Time Delayed Neural Network (but I realise the question about the differences between them would suit best to stats.stackexchange)